# Agregando Posts temporales en el Resultado del WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy tratando de modificar el Objeto que me devuelve el resultado de `WP_Query` para añadirle posts falsos (que en realidad son noticias que se alimentan de un `RSS` parseado), y estoy atascado en ello..

A ver si me explico un poco mejor. Tengo esto:

```
$posts = new WP_Query($args); 
//$posts->posts trae 2 paginas reales creadas en el WP pero quiero agregar 10 paginas mas que la parseo en $xml
```

Es decir si hago un `print_r` de `$posts` trae esto:

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => Array
        (
            [offset] => 0
            [posts_per_page] => 12
            [post_type] => post
            [post_status] => publish
            [orderby] => date
            [order] => DESC
        )

    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [offset] => 0
            [posts_per_page] => 12
            [post_type] => post
            [post_status] => publish
            [orderby] => date
            [order] => DESC
            [error] => 
            [m] => 
            [p] => 0
            [post_parent] => 
            [subpost] => 
            [subpost_id] => 
            [attachment] => 
            [attachment_id] => 0
            [name] => 
            [static] => 
            [pagename] => 
            [page_id] => 0
            [second] => 
            [minute] => 
            [hour] => 
            [day] => 0
            [monthnum] => 0
            [year] => 0
            [w] => 0
            [category_name] => 
            [tag] => 
            [cat] => 
            [tag_id] => 
            [author] => 
            [author_name] => 
            [feed] => 
            [tb] => 
            [paged] => 0
            [meta_key] => 
            [meta_value] => 
            [preview] => 
            [s] => 
            [sentence] => 
            [title] => 
            [fields] => 
            [menu_order] => 
            [embed] => 
            [category__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [category__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [category__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [post__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post_name__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag_slug__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag_slug__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [post_parent__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post_parent__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [author__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [author__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
            [suppress_filters] => 
            [cache_results] => 1
            [update_post_term_cache] => 1
            [lazy_load_term_meta] => 1
            [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
            [nopaging] => 
            [comments_per_page] => 50
            [no_found_rows] => 
        )

    [tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                )

            [relation] => AND
            [table_aliases:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [queried_terms] => Array
                (
                )

            [primary_table] => wp_posts
            [primary_id_column] => ID
        )

    [meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                )

            [relation] => 
            [meta_table] => 
            [meta_id_column] => 
            [primary_table] => 
            [primary_id_column] => 
            [table_aliases:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [clauses:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [has_or_relation:protected] => 
        )

    [date_query] => 
    [request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12
    [posts] => Array
        (
            [0] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 88
                    [post_author] => 1
                    [post_date] => 2017-08-08 07:27:25
                    [post_date_gmt] => 2017-08-08 07:27:25
                    [post_content] => Hola Esto es un Loren 
                    [post_title] => Lo he Encontrado
                    [post_excerpt] => 
                    [post_status] => publish
                    [comment_status] => closed
                    [ping_status] => closed
                    [post_password] => 
                    [post_name] => lo-he-encontrado
                    [to_ping] => 
                    [pinged] => 
                    [post_modified] => 2017-08-28 16:22:12
                    [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-08-28 16:22:12
                    [post_content_filtered] => 
                    [post_parent] => 0
                    [guid] => https://www.midominio.com/?p=88
                    [menu_order] => 0
                    [post_type] => post
                    [post_mime_type] => 
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [filter] => raw
                )

            [1] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 58
                    [post_author] => 1
                    [post_date] => 2017-08-03 11:26:42
                    [post_date_gmt] => 2017-08-03 11:26:42
                    [post_content] => Texto en el Content
                    [post_title] => Loren Ipsum Noticia
                    [post_excerpt] => 
                    [post_status] => publish
                    [comment_status] => closed
                    [ping_status] => closed
                    [post_password] => 
                    [post_name] => sluggggggg
                    [to_ping] => 
                    [pinged] => 
                    [post_modified] => 2017-08-28 16:22:12
                    [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-08-28 16:22:12
                    [post_content_filtered] => 
                    [post_parent] => 0
                    [guid] => https://www.midominio.com/?p=58
                    [menu_order] => 0
                    [post_type] => post
                    [post_mime_type] => 
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [filter] => raw
                )






//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// QUIERO AÑADIR MAS REGISTROS ACA DESDE UNA FUENTE EXTERNA COMO XML QUE LO PARSEO A ARRAY
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////





        )

    [post_count] => 2
    [current_post] => -1
    [in_the_loop] => 
    [post] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 88
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2017-08-08 07:27:25
            [post_date_gmt] => 2017-08-08 07:27:25
            [post_content] => Hola Esto es un Loren
            [post_title] => Lo he Encontrado
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => lo-he-encontrado
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2017-08-28 16:22:12
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-08-28 16:22:12
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => https://www.midominio.com/?p=88
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => post
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [comment_count] => 0
    [current_comment] => -1
    [found_posts] => 2
    [max_num_pages] => 1
    [max_num_comment_pages] => 0
    [is_single] => 
    [is_preview] => 
    [is_page] => 
    [is_archive] => 
    [is_date] => 
    [is_year] => 
    [is_month] => 
    [is_day] => 
    [is_time] => 
    [is_author] => 
    [is_category] => 
    [is_tag] => 
    [is_tax] => 
    [is_search] => 
    [is_feed] => 
    [is_comment_feed] => 
    [is_trackback] => 
    [is_home] => 1
    [is_404] => 
    [is_embed] => 
    [is_paged] => 
    [is_admin] => 
    [is_attachment] => 
    [is_singular] => 
    [is_robots] => 
    [is_posts_page] => 
    [is_post_type_archive] => 
    [query_vars_hash:WP_Query:private] => eece7ee429fd38bda3abe3ac6b0c63da
    [query_vars_changed:WP_Query:private] => 
    [thumbnails_cached] => 
    [stopwords:WP_Query:private] => 
    [compat_fields:WP_Query:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => query_vars_hash
            [1] => query_vars_changed
        )

    [compat_methods:WP_Query:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => init_query_flags
            [1] => parse_tax_query
        )

)
```

Ahora bien si intento con:

```
foreach ($xml as $noticia) {
    $posts->found_posts = count($noticia);
    foreach ($noticia as $key => $value) {
        $idNoticia = $value['idNoticia'];
        $titulo=$value['title'];
        $link=$value['url'];;
        $descripcion = $value['description'];
        $descripcion_corta = $value['description_corta'];
        $fechanoticia = strftime("%d-%b-%Y", strtotime($value['data']));
        $posts->posts[$key]->ID = $idNoticia;
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_title = $titulo;
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_content = $descripcion;
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_excerpt = $descripcion_corta;
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_date = $fechavc;
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_date_gmt = $fechavc;
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_modified = $fechavc;
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_modified_gmt = $fechavc;
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_name = sanitize_title_with_dashes($titulo);
        $posts->posts[$key]->guid = $link;
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_type = 'post';
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_author = 1;
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_status = 'publish';
        $posts->posts[$key]->comment_status = 'closed';
        $posts->posts[$key]->ping_status = 'closed';
        $posts->posts[$key]->to_ping = '';
        $posts->posts[$key]->pinged = '';
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_content_filtered = '';
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_parent = 0;
        $posts->posts[$key]->menu_order = '';
        $posts->posts[$key]->post_mime_type = '';
        $posts->posts[$key]->comment_count = 0;
        $posts->posts[$key]->filter = 'raw';
    }
}
```

Despues de añadirlas, al realizar un `print_r($posts->posts)` si me las muestra pero tipo `stdClass Object`, pero no funciona, debajo al hacer el render de las grid no muestra dichas nuevas agregadas.

Estube leyendo pero hablan de un action llamado `pre_get_posts`, pero sinceramente no se por donde comenzar respecto a esto.

Comment: Sugiero que pruebes con algo como esto: [Load WordPress RSS Feed's in a custom PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26658665/5587982)

Comment: No acabo de entender

Hice

    $posts = new WP_Query($args);


    $posts->query_vars['feed'] == 'http://ep00.epimg.net/rss/elpais/portada.xml';
    do_feed();

Pero no hace nada.